# What should I do about a pin hole leak in pvc water pipe?

Tags: pvc

I have tried JB Weld products, epoxy, water epoxy, and water tape.  I do not want to replace the pipe--just fix it for now. The pipe is a cold water supply.

Comment: it's ridiculously easy to repair PVC by just cutting out the bad section. why have you not done that yet?

Comment: Anything glued on the outside is resisting pressure after it has exited the containment. Think Blister. The pressure under the blister is as high as the internal pressure of the pipe till it strips the patch off and starts leaking again... Temporary patches like you've tried are temporary and from personal experience may only gain you 24-48 hours which if it's your copper main hot water lines, gives you just enough time to find all the fittings and pipe so you can spend your weekend finding all 20 other incipient pinhole leaks as you R&R the whole system.

Comment: Home Depot sells a pipe repair kit.  You put a blob of epoxy putty on the pinhole, forming a hard scab that resists blistering.  Then you wrap fiberglass resin tape around the pipe, which acts as a bandage to hold the epoxy putty in place.

Answer (score 10):

Your best bet to fix the leak is to turn off the water, drain the line, and then cut out the bad section and replace with some new glued in fittings and pipe pieces.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. PVC is unreliable once punctured. Anything squeezed, glued or otherwise attached to the outside might as well be bubble gum on a dam.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe Repair Clamp

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://www.lowes.com/pd_24521-143-PP24001_0__

There are quite a few different styles; however, almost all of them are **designed for metal pipes**. Personally, with PVC I still suggest replace a section of the pipe, but if you can't this will get by in a pinch.

Make sure to prepare the surface. Turn the water supply off, sand the area (get rid of your epoxies and rough up the surface). For a good seal, I'd add some 100% silicone "caulking". then put the clamp on. The clamps come with a rubber gasket and if you are using a universal size one then be extra careful not to crack the pipe, it takes a bit but is surprisingly easy when using tools. Allow a couple of hours for the silicone to dry (most dry times listed are expecting surface air to help dry/cure it so if you can manage it leave it overnight)

Comment: Works only if the leak is in a straight part of the line (pinhole unlikely in PVC, more likely a split) and not a joint. If the joint is leaking due to bad solvent weld, replacement is the only way that the leak will be repaired. And silicone applied between the rubber and piping will tunnel unless allowed to fully cure.

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up in the first page on Google and there's no mention of a Sharkbite, so I thought I would necro-answer.  Sharkbites are compression fittings available at Home Depot.  They function similar to a repair clamp, but they seem like they seal better to me.  They're very easy to install, as well.

http://did-it-myself.com/fix-a-pinhole-leak-with-sharkbite/

Comment: Cut the pipe and put in a shark bite.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

I had a puncture happen in an area that cutting the pipe and adding a coupling was going to be a super mission. What I ended up doing was cutting a coupling in half (so you get 2 u shaped pieces), gluing it on, and using a hose clamp to tighten it. This was for a sprinkler pipe so not nearly as much constant pressure as a house pipe but it's been holding for weeks now.

Comment: Inside the house this might be a good temporary fix for a short time or an emergency. But I wouldn't want to rely on that working indefinitely. But certainly could buy some time.

Answer (score 1):

By using a Ice Maker self tapping shut off you can place the the nail of the shut off in the pinhole and screw clamp down [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting idea, but it depends on the PVC leak being a perfect circle, which seems unlikely.

Comment: So just leave the needle in i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Bondo fiberglass resin, while a little messy, worked to patch a leaking PVC sump pump pipe joint.  The pipe location was in a tight spot making cutting it out a much bigger pain.  Two other products that are less messy (than fiberglass) and might do the job -- Fiber Fix and Perma-Wrap.

Comment: So this wasn't under high pressure?

Answer (score 0):

Watts quick connect. Simply cut out section where the pinhole is and stab the pipe into the quick connect. Easy as 123. I've even done this with copper and it works great. No more soldering or worrying if the water is out of the pipe. You will not regret it!

Comment: For followers that's a "push fit" connecting like shark bite :)

Answer (score 0):

Sombody went through a wall in my rv with a finishing with a finishing nail. The pipe it punctured was a 1" long 1/2" pipe, In such a tight spot I couldn't use a saw, almost got a small cut off wheel, but instead used a ratcheting pvc cutter (looks like scissors or pruners, $12 at home depot) cut the pipe near the hole. Used Oatey brand "handy pack" which contains purple primer and medium orange cpvc cement,  and used it to "weld" on a $.73 coupler fitting. This will be a permanent fix. Also I installed this on a water line for the inside/outside showers, toilet, and bathroom sink. Not drinking water so I didn't even ask if it was drinking water safe! I'm sure it would be fine after thoroughly running water or if you have a high grade water filter.